# How to resolve: [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property ... of undefined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In a Vue project, I'm trying to return a URL for each tool in a set of tools.

#### The Context

This is the relevant snippet in a `ToolDetails.vue` file:

```
<script>
import { mapActions } from 'vuex';
import ToolFacts from '@/components/ToolFacts.vue';
import Matrix from '@/components/Matrix.vue';
import json from '../../models/content/tool_details.json';

export default {
  name: 'tool-details',
  components: {
    ToolFacts,
    Matrix,
  },
  data: () => ({
    // tool: '',
  }),
  created() {
    this.checkValidToolName();
    // this.getToolName();
  },
  computed: {
    tool() {
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      return Object.values(json).find(entity => entity.tool_url.toLowerCase() === this.$route.params.name.toLowerCase());
    },
  },
  methods: {
    getToolName() {
      this.tool = json[this.$route.params.name];
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      return Object.values(json).for.find(entity => entity.tool_url.toLowerCase() === this.$route.params.name.toLowerCase());
    },
    getAssetPath(assetPath) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      return require(`../assets/${assetPath}`);
    },
    ...mapActions(['SET_PRESELECTED_TOOL']),
    compareTool() {
      this.SET_PRESELECTED_TOOL(this.tool.name)
        .then(this.$router.push('/compare'));
    },
    checkValidToolName() {
      if (!this.tool) {
        this.$router.push('/filter');
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

`tool_details.json` is formatted like this:

```
{
  "Example Tool": {
    "name": "Example Tool Name",
    "tool_url": "example-tool-url",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

#### The Problem

The URLs are generated as `undefined` in the browser source code and the console displays this error:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js:619 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined"

found in

---> <ToolDetails> at src/views/ToolDetails.vue
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>

vue.runtime.esm.js:1888 TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    at ToolDetails.vue:78
    at Array.find (<anonymous>)
    at VueComponent.tool (ToolDetails.vue:78)
    at Watcher.get (vue.runtime.esm.js:4473)
    at Watcher.evaluate (vue.runtime.esm.js:4578)
    at VueComponent.computedGetter [as tool] (vue.runtime.esm.js:4830)
    at Object.get (vue.runtime.esm.js:2072)
    at Proxy.render (ToolDetails.vue?bf00:13)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (vue.runtime.esm.js:3542)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js:4060)
```

When I drop in a debugger, `json` is defined but not `entity`.

I've tried defining `entity` like this:

```
const entity = [];
```

and this:

```
const entity = {};
```

but I get the same console error plus the ES Lint error:

```
'entity' is assigned a value but never used
```

How can I resolve that console error to return the correct URL for each tool?

Comment: Looks like you have a typo in your `getToolName` method. `Object.values(json).for.find(en` The `for` method does not exist. If that doesn't fix it try to see what is in your `tool_details` object and see if it misses the `tool_url` property.

Comment: Thanks @EmielZuurbier. I removed the `for` method. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved. Apparently, the issue was being caused from another file, `ToolCard.vue`, which had this in it:

```
<div class="learn-cta">
  <router-link tag="a" :to="`tool/${data.tool_url}`">
    Learn More
  </router-link>
  <img src="@/assets/icons/arrow_blue.svg" />
</div>
```

referencing `tool_cards.json`, in which I needed to add a `tool_url` line. That made the URLs properly generate for each tool link to work and the `undefined` error disappeared.